# Amazon Prime Video totally freezes/crashes Raspberry Pi 4 in Chromium

Tags: video, chromium, crash

Since the Widevine support is available for Raspbian I'm able to watch Netflix and Amazon Prime Video on the Raspberry Pi just using the Chromium Browser.

I have, however, a strange behaviour when trying to browse the Amazon Prime Video Webpage when suddenly the whole system just freezes and only hard reboot (unplugging power) will reset the system. This happens every time. I can open the Page, see the Movies and then the whole system just freezes.

Netflix, youtube is working fine.

Has anyone else ever experienced this behaviour? Raspbian is updated and upgraded.

Comment: I can confirm the same. From a few months ago until now, this is the behavior. Sometimes you are successful and the movie loads, and you can watch the whole movie. Other times, while deciding which movie to watch, the system freezes. To clarify the issue, it is not the browser, but the entire system that freezes.

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem still exists: I had the [same case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/139686/149888), but with Netflix and not with Amazon Prime Video. For me it helped to set the settings Show bookmarks bar' and 'Use system title bar and borders' under appearance

Comment: yeah, but the OP did say Netflix and Youtube is working fine.