# Netflix in Chromium freeze complete pi

Tags: video, chromium, crash

My Pi 4 (8GB) has been crashing since yesterday whenever you want to watch a movie in Chromium via Netflix. However, the first five minutes of the film run through without any problems.

Other websites (e.g. Stackoverflow and Youtube) work in Chromium and other actions (e.g. zipping and moving many files) on the Pi work fine.

I have not applied major updates before, I check for updates at irregular weekly intervals, so the Pi is mostly up to date.

When the Pi freezes, the green LED (for read & write actions) doesn't light up at all.

The technical info:

Version Pi

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: raspberrypi
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 123456789asdfforwin
           Boot ID: niwroffdsa987654321
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.61-v7l+
      Architecture: arm
```

Version Chromium

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium-browser -version
Chromium 104.0.5112.105 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 11
```

If it helps troubleshooting, I'll eat a broom, but the movie I use to recreate the behavior is 'The School for Good and Evil'.

I found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136918/amazon-prime-video-totally-freezes-crashes-raspberry-pi-4-in-chromium) that has the same behavior, but with Amazon and no solution.

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74650/raspberry-pi-3-freezes) is similar however the answers did not help me:

- I use the official power supply for the Pi for normal use and when testing I used a much more powerful laptop charger (65W) and still the behavior occurred.
- I ran `sudo e2fsck -cvf /dev/sdb2` on another PC with the SD card, but no bad sectors were reported.

This is my first case where the Pi completely crashes, I do not yet have any idea what logs I need to look into (though I have not yet done a search for it).

I haven't tried to reinstall the SD card yet, because I would like to solve the problem in a different way.

**Netflix crashes my Pi4 and i want to know why**

**Added Info 1:**

I was running `htop` on the side when the freeze occurred:
Each core was under 40% and the RAM was under 50% utilization

Comment: maybe Netflix made an update to their servers.

Comment: What temperature does your Pi reach? How much memory us in use?

Comment: @CoderMike under 80°C, otherwise the attached fan would start; i can touch the chip without problem, its very warm but not hot. And ca. 30-40% of the RAM are in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to Chromium's  appearance settings: after I set 'Show bookmarks bar' and 'Use system title bar and borders', the behavior stopped